# 64 bit number support in CUDA

Tags: cuda, 64-bit, nvidia

I kind of found various opinions on this topic, so this is why I decided to ask here. My question is starting from what computing capability is int64_t supported on CUDA. I am running cuda 5 on a Quadro770M and the following code works without a problem, although I read that 64 bit unsigned are supported starting from compute capability 1.3. So what is the real answer to that question ?

```
__device__ void printBinary(int64_t a) {
    int bits[64];
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 64; i++) {
        bits[63 - i] = (a >> i) & 1; 
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 64; ++i) {
        cuPrintf("%d", bits[i]);
    }
    cuPrintf("\n");
    cuPrintf("%016llX", a);
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

64 bit integers (signed and unsigned) are supported on all CUDA-capable hardware (though operations on them map to multiple native 32-bit instructions).

Compute capability 1.3 introduced 64-bit *floating point* numbers (which are natively supported).

Comment: I understand now. So does the use of 64 bit numbers introduce significant penalty on performance due to the mapping of operations?

Comment: It depends on the operation. 64-bit addition and subtraction can be synthesized efficiently from 32-bit operations (2 or 3 instructions depending on compute capability). Multiplication requires longer instruction sequences (on the order of 10 to 20 instructions depending on architecture), and division and modulo require extensive emulation sequences (60-100+ instructions, depending on architecture). You can examine all the details by disassembling code with cuobjdump.